# Change the value of EnableSnapAssistFlyout with immediate effect

Tags: windows, notifications, registry, sendmessage

This is a project in C++ win32 running on a Windows 11 about enable / disabling to shop the Snap Layouts when hovering over a window's maximize button. The changes are shown in the Registry of Windows but without effect.

I can update the key "EnableSnapAssistFlyout" at the subtree "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced" of the system Registry by calling the function `RegSetValueEx(hKey, TEXT("EnableSnapAssistFlyout"), 0, dwType, (LPBYTE)&dwValue, dwSize);` with success, but the effect does not occur immediately. However, doing this from Windows Settings -> System -> Multitasking -> Unfold 'Snap Windows' -> Disable 'Show snap layouts...', the effect is instant. I also check the Registry Editor and indeed the changes are done. Moreover, if I do the changes in the Registry Editor directly, the effect does not occur immediately too, just like using the RegSetValueEx function. I am suspecting that a sort of notification is required in here, but I have tested with sending a broadcast message too but without results with `SendMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SETTINGCHANGE, 0, (LPARAM)TEXT("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Explorer\\Advanced"));`.

How should the option at the Settings be notifying all windows about the change?